# Monty Hall Python Simulation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

So I was working on simulating the monty hall problem in python, and I obtained the solution from the Harvad Stats 111 course. The function below is supposed to reveal a door that isn't the prize door or the guess door. However, I'm confused as to what two parts of the functions do. First of all, what does the bad.any() do, and why is it necessary. Isn't it enough to simply say "if not bad". And secondly what exactly does the last line achieve.

Thanks a lot

```
def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):

#strategy: generate random answers, and
#keep updating until they satisfy the rule
#that they aren't a prizedoor or a guess
result = np.random.randint(0, 3, prizedoors.size)
while True:
    bad = (result == prizedoors) | (result == guesses)
    if not bad.any(): #DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS
        return result
    result[bad] = np.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum()) #DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS
```

Comment: *"Isn't it enough to simply say `if not bad`"* - try it and see!

Comment: Note that this is using `numpy` and isn't standard behaviour in Python; you can't just compare a value with a normal iterable and get an iterable as a result.

Comment: `if not bad.any()` is more readable as `if bad.all()`. Maybe the person who wrote the code thinks that `not bad.any()` will be faster due to short circuiting, but this is clearly a micro-optimization!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the equality operator on `numpy.ndarray` (numpy arrays) , they give a list of booleans which contain the equality of each element of the array (like first element in the return array is the equality of first element of both arrays.

`|` is the bitwise or operator in python, it is used to bitwise or the two truth arrays returned by the two equality comparisons, so that it returns true at `ith` index if its `True` at the `ith` index for any of the arrays it gets as its operand.

Now `bad` is an array of boolean values, trying to directly do `if not bad` would not work, because it would always return True, as bad is an array (and any non-zero/None value in python is true (in python 2.x that is)) .

So you have to do [`bad.any()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) which checks if any of the elements in `bad` array is True, if it is then it returns `True` , otherwise it returns `False`.

Example -

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rn

n1 = np.arange(0,10)

n2 = np.arange(5,15)

rn.shuffle(n1)
rn.shuffle(n2)

print(n1)
>>> [8 2 3 7 9 5 0 6 1 4]
print(n2)
>>> [ 8  5 14 12 13  7 10 11  6  9]
d = n1 == n2
print(d)
>>> [ True False False False False False False False False False]
```

As you can see `d` is an array of boolean values.

```
print(d.any())
>>> True
```

This is true, as there is a true element in `d` .

Comment: Sorry to dig this topic up, but I was wondering if its ok to change bad.sum() to len(result[bad]) ?